# Read .txt file and analyze

Tags: python, huffman-code

I'm working Huffman coding of any .txt file, so first I need to analyse this text file. I need to read it, then analyse.
I need "exit" like table:

---

letter | frequency(how many times same latter repeated)  |  Huffman code(this will come later)

---

I started with:

```
 f = open('test.txt', 'r')    #open test.tx
 for lines in f:
     print lines          #to ensure if all work...
```

---

How can I order reading characters from file in alphabetic order:

```
with open("test.txt") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        for char in line:
            frequencies[char] += 1
```

???Many thanks

---

```
Well I tried like this:
frequencies = collections.defaultdict(int)
with open("test.txt") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        for char in line:
            frequencies[char] += 1


 frequencies = [(count, char) for char, count in frequencies.iteritems()]
 frequencies.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

But compiler return me an "error"
    enter code here

I need this alphabetic order **in for loop**, not at end at  frequencies...

Comment: Any objections to retagging this homework?

Comment: I see to problems with what you tried. The last two lines have a leading space character and there are no `import collections` and `import operator` statements. Fix those and it should work fine.

Comment: what do you mean you need them in alphabetic order in the for loop? That doesn't make any sense. You would have to read the file all at once and then sort that before looping over it. What does that add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your table of frequencies, I would use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). This will only iterate over the data once.

```
import collections
import operator

frequencies = collections.defaultdict(int)
with open(filename) as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        for char in line:
            frequencies[char] += 1


frequencies = [(count, char) for char, count in frequencies.iteritems()]
frequencies.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: This is basically how I did it when I actually wrote a Huffman implementation myself. (Except my text "symbols" weren't individual characters... ;) )

Comment: @thaking, I really don't know much about Python. You might be better off just creating a new question so that the experts can see it.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('test.txt') as f: data = f.read()
table = dict((c, data.count(c)) for c in set(data))
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this will iterate over `data` once for every character that occurs in the file.

Comment: And an additional time to create the set. It's designed for neatness, not efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I made this solution using a `collections.Counter()`:

```
import re
import collections


if __name__ == '__main__':
    is_letter = re.compile('[A-Za-z]')

    frequencies = collections.Counter()
    with open(r'text.txt') as f_in:
        for line in f_in:
            for char in line:
                if is_letter.match(char):
                    frequencies[char.lower()] += 1

    # Sort characters 
    characters = [x[0] for x in frequencies.most_common()]
    characters.sort()
    for c in characters:
        print c, '|', str(frequencies[c])
```

The regular expression `is_letter` is used to filter for only the characters we are interested in.
It gives output that looks like this.

```
a | 177
b | 29
c | 7
d | 167
e | 374
f | 58
g | 100
h | 44
i | 135
j | 21
k | 64
l | 125
m | 85
n | 191
o | 105
p | 34
r | 185
s | 130
t | 146
u | 34
v | 68
x | 1
y | 14
```